# Docker port 80:80 127.0.0.1

Tags: laravel, docker, port

Im having a huge issue and I can't get round it

Basically i went through the Laravel installation and installed homestead 7 and im using virtual box... vagrant

Now before this I'm using docker to run other application through it... which worked and it looks like something i've done is using the same port so I now cant use docker on that port

> Cannot start service website: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint distinctly_website_1 (edc81f653cb3ac8c2af9b7ce070d0a0ccbb3ec255af452338ff4677ce99b156a): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:80: unexpected error (Failure EADDRINUSE)
>   ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

I just need some help with removing this conflict with the port so I can run my docker applications. I dont care about anything than docker

Comment: It's Laravel and not larvel!

Comment: apologies lewis

Comment: One of two:
1) you have another process running, using port 80, eventually your virtualbox/vagrant or another web development stack (xampp/mamp/apache/...).

2) under 1024, system ports require adminstrative privileges, so... you need to run your docker using sudo (?)... But usually, docker runs with their own user/group (with privileges), so... your user need to be added to docker group.

Answer (score 1):

Just an update found a solution

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

this stopped the service that was conflicting and i can now use my docker image

Answer (score 0):

Just use a different port on your host when running the container. something like `docker run -p 8080:80 IMAGE_NAME`.

So your container will be available on the host on port 8080, but it talks to the container (and application) on port 80.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine which process is listening on the port by running the command

```
netstat -nlp | grep 80
```

Once you find that program, you can kill it by running

```
kill <pid>
```

Answer (score 0):

netstat: option requires an argument -- p
Usage:  netstat [-AaLlnW] [-f address_family | -p protocol]

```
netstat [-gilns] [-f address_family]
netstat -i | -I interface [-w wait] [-abdgRtS]
netstat -s [-s] [-f address_family | -p protocol] [-w wait]
netstat -i | -I interface -s [-f address_family | -p protocol]
netstat -m [-m]
netstat -r [-Aaln] [-f address_family]
netstat -rs [-s]
```